# Why is Frigga (queen of Asgard) not taken to healing room?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world, thor

In the first part of [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(film)), when Volstagg returns injured from Jotunheim, Odin, the king of Asgard orders to send him to healing room. Which portrays that Asgard has a healing room.

Then why is Frigga not sent to healing room in the second part of the [Thor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_The_Dark_World) movie, when attacked by Kurse of  Svartalfheim? Wasn't there enough time to send her there?

Comment: Frigga was dead already, healing room can't resurrect

Answer (score 4):

Volstagg was injured but alive. Frigga was stabbed through the heart and died immediately. Odin and Thor are both warriors who can recognize fatal wounds. And Odin holds his wife. He can clearly see that sure is dead as he holds her.